# The rationale of QR algorithm for computing eigenvectors

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, numerical-linear-algebra

For a symmetric matrix $A$, the rationale for the success of applying QR to compute the spectral decomposition of $A = UDU^T$ is, for large $k$, the QR factorization of $A^k = Q_kR_k$ obeys,
\begin{equation}
Q_k\approx U.
\end{equation}
Could anyone help to justify the approximation?

Thanks,
Jack

Comment: QR is interpreted today as simultaneous subspace iteration (a generalization of the power method to subspaces) on a flag of Krylov subspaces. I suggest you to take a look at a book such as Watkins' *The matrix eigenvalue problem*.